# Efficiency of giving function as list in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

When you supply a function as the old list in a list comprehension like this

```
my_new_list = [x * 2 for x in list_maker()]
```

is `list_maker()` called each time a new `x` is grabbed?

I'm wondering because I want to know if it'd be more efficient to do this

```
my_old_list = list_maker()
my_new_list = [x * 2 for x in my_old_list]
```

Thanks!

Comment: I propose an experiment. Define `list_maker()` so that it prints a message every time it is called. Then run your code and see how many times that message is printed.

Comment: No `list_maker` isn't called each time. That wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: In regards to performance that is what timeit is for

Comment: If `list_maker` yields values, it will re-enter the function, but the function isn't *called*, so to speak.

Comment: in yor example list_maker() will be called once only.

Comment: @PeterWood What do you mean?

Comment: @Ellburrito Essentially python will look for iterator in the list comprehension.
So this iterator will be called until it raises StopIteration.
If your function is iterator - it will be called many times. If your function  returns collectible, then Iterator for this collectible will be called many times ( just return next item). But your function will be called just once. At least this is how I understand it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer, like most questions of "which is more effecient?", is "it depends".

Traditionally, `list_maker` would be called once, so whether you call it in the list comprehension or outside and assign to a variable makes no difference(1).

However (and this is what @PeterWood is referring to), `list_maker` could be a [generator](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#generators), which would cause it to be *entered* repeatedly (which is not exactly the same as *called* repeatedly, but probably close enough). (See also [PEP 255](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/).)

The question of which is more effecient, however, is not clear-cut -- a regular function returning the whole list would use more memory than a generator, which might or might not be more expensive.

---

(1) Except that the memory used to store the result of `list_maker` can be freed immediately after the list compreshension compeletes, where are the `my_new_list` would have to go out of scope unreferenced first.